# cloud function return 400 bad requests

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I have this code, basically I want to extract the zip file in GCS that triggered by HTTP Request.

```
import functions_framework
import os
import tempfile
import zipfile
from google.cloud import storage

def extract_zip(event):
    """Cloud Function to extract contents of a zip file uploaded to GCS."""
    
    # Specify your GCS bucket name
    bucket_name = "deepcare-dataset"

    print(bucket_name)

    # Extract information from the event
    file_name = event["name"]
    file_path = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}"
    print(file_path)

    # Set up a temporary directory to extract files
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    # Create a storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    print('Downloading...')
    # Download the zip file from GCS
    blob = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name).get_blob(file_name)
    download_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(download_path)

    print('Extracting...')
    # Extract the contents of the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(download_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(temp_dir)

    print('Uploading...')
    # Upload the extracted files back to GCS
    for extracted_file in os.listdir(temp_dir):
        extracted_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, extracted_file)
        destination_blob_name = f"{file_name[:-4]}/{extracted_file}"

        # Upload the extracted file to GCS
        storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name).blob(destination_blob_name).upload_from_filename(extracted_file_path)
        print(f'Uploaded for:', destination_blob_name)

    # Clean up the temporary directory
    os.remove(download_path)
    os.rmdir(temp_dir)

    print(f"Extraction and upload completed for {file_name}")


@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
        if name == 'myzip.zip':
            extract_zip(request_args)
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
        if name == 'myzip.zip':
            extract_zip(request_args)
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(name)
```

Here are the logging info that verbose but didn't give me information the reason why 400 bad requests error. Note that, the error only happened if the body request with POST is

```
{
  "name":"myzip.zip"
}
```

other than that `("name" : "foo")` is 200 OK. I suspect it was because my extract function error. But it's not clear that whether the 400 response come from my function or something else since cloud logging didn't give me clear reason. It was just saying warning.

LOG:

```
{
  "insertId": "656b0fa30002f03d0c947a91",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "POST",
    "requestUrl": "https://asia-southeast2-***.cloudfunctions.net/function-1",
    "requestSize": "464",
    "status": 400,
    "responseSize": "819",
    "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.34.0",
    "remoteIp": "104.28.254.47",
    "serverIp": "216.239.36.54",
    "latency": "0.005019129s",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "revision_name": "function-1-00001-qid",
      "location": "asia-southeast2",
      "service_name": "function-1",
      "project_id": "***",
      "configuration_name": "function-1"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-12-02T11:06:11.180972Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "labels": {
    "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
    "instanceId": "0087599d42c23459cbb07b0680f42627a501194e4825c912c5119b703c25894fe2d5caf7a1bbe0ce42006b2c6f646d2cd6ec68f6f5fb2ad91fa39a17e6eaa78789"
  },
  "logName": "projects/***/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests",
  "trace": "projects/***/traces/98c21d5c3145fa7af9b5bc5f2d53b523",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-12-02T11:06:11.194091644Z",
  "spanId": "14357157746819527854",
  "traceSampled": true
}
```

Any there idea how do I debug this

Comment: Your post shows Python code, but the log shows `PostmanRuntime`. The log message is not from the code you posted.

Comment: Have you checked [this troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#400_Bad_Request) document. Also make sure you have given proper roles to your service account And can you share logs from your code?